# RDP + NLA + VPN: Smartcard authentication fails

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, smartcard

- Inside my company I can login into RDP (NLA is turned on) using my smartcard.
- Outside my company I'm not able to login into RDP over VPN using my smartcard when I'm using a non-domain PC. I get the following error:

> The remote computer that you are trying to connect to requires Network Level Authentication (NLA), but your Windows domain controller cannot be contacted to perform NLA ...

- Outside my company I'm still able to login into RDP over VPN using the username and password when I'm using a non-domain PC.
- Outside my company I was able to login to RDP (when NLA was turned off) over VPN using my smartcard when I'm using a non-domain PC.
- Outside my company I'm still able to login into RDP (NLA is turned on) over VPN using the smartcard when I'm using a domain PC.

Comment: Well, _does_ the client have access to any domain controller (for Kerberos especially)? Have you [checked](https://www.wireshark.org/) what the client is actually trying to contact?

Comment: @user1686 Which ports is Kerberos using?

Comment: Have you talked to your Domain or VPN admins. It might be their policy to not expose the DCs to outside non-domain PCs.